# Using BCrypt password hashing with Spring Security Grails plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, bcrypt

I'm trying to use the BCrypt password hashing in my Grails app that's using the Spring Security plugin. I've enabled BCrypt by adding the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
```

And I've defined the following codec to simplify using BCrypt to encode paswords:

```
public class PasswordCodec {

    // it doesn't seem to be possible to dependency-inject codecs, so lookup the bean ourselves
    @Lazy
    private static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('passwordEncoder')

    static encode = { str ->
        passwordEncoder.encodePassword(str.toString(), null)
    }
}
```

When I start the application in dev mode the database is bootstrapped with a few accounts (each of which has the same password, e.g.

```
3.times { i ->
    def username = "user$i"
    def password = "secret".encodeAsPassword()

    new User(username: username, password: password).save()
    // also assign the user a role
}
```

If I look in the database, I see that the encoded value of each of these user's password is different! So it's no surprise that when a user attempts to login and enters a password of "secret", the BCrypt-encoded password value doesn't match what's saved in the database, because it seems that the BCrypt-encoded value of a String somehow changes over time.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but I've no idea what?

Comment: I assume that your User domain doesn't have the typical s2 quickstart code that handles password encoding?

Comment: Also, I think salting is enabled by default now, which is based on username and thus would be different salts for each password: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/passwords.html#salt ... assuming you still have the generated s2 quickstart code in place.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore no, I don't do any password encoding in the User class itself (I didn't use s2-quickstart)

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I encode the password myself in `PasswordCodec` and pass `null` for the salt parameter

Comment: Completely odd then. Perhaps Burt will pop by and offer some assistance. I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you are doing and it mimics what we use to have to do in Spring ages ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Often password hashes are identical given the same input (and very occasionally with different inputs). But bcrypt and others generate a different hash each time. This isn't a problem however, because the `PasswordEncoder` interface has both the `String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt)` method to generate hashes, but also the `boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt)` method to validate them.

With simpler hashes like MD5, SHA-1, etc. the process for verification is simply re-encoding the cleartext password and checking that it's the same as the stored hashed value. The process is a lot more complicated with bcrypt, but the end result is the same - it doesn't check for *equality*, but instead that they're *equivalent*. So if you hash the same password twice and compare them with `isPasswordValid` it will return `true`.

Comment: How is this deprecated PasswordEncoder different from this [PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html), other than providing a salt by user in the former case? (Out of context of question)

Comment: I haven't looked closely at the differences, but I'm planning on migrating to the newer interface.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I completely missed the `isPasswordValid` method, thanks a lot