# Grails 3.3.0 with postgresql 10.1 as database and spring-security-core gives "object references an unsaved transient instance" error

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I have to make a Grails 3.3.0 web interface for my internship with PostgreSQL version 10.1 as database and spring-security-core version 3.2.0.

I've installed PostgreSQL on my Linux laptop and created the webInterfaceDev database with the user Postgres.

However, every time I want to start the project I get the error "object references an unsaved transient instance".

This is the error that I get:

```
2017-11-23 11:26:55.634 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.domain.auth.User
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:2051)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:2020)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1950)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.listForCriteria(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:716)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.query.AbstractHibernateQuery.list(AbstractHibernateQuery.java:706)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.invokeQuery(FindAllByFinder.java:54)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder$1.doInSession(FindAllByFinder.java:48)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:319)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:42)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FindAllByFinder.doInvokeInternal(FindAllByFinder.java:45)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:254)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:392)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.FinderMethod$invoke$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:185)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.staticMethodMissing(GormEntity.groovy:756)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1446)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:899)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at com.domain.auth.UserRole.staticMethodMissing(UserRole.groovy)
        at com.domain.auth.UserRole.$static_methodMissing(UserRole.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1499)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1487)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.domain.auth.User.getAuthorities(User.groovy:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:85)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
        at web_interface.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:9)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:535)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:528)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:504)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
        at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:261)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at web_interface.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Below is the code that I used:

grails-app/conf/application.yml

```
 ---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: web_interface
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    #mem database driver and password
    #driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    #username: sa
    #password:

    #PostgreSQL driver and password
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: password

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update #use create-drop or update
            #Use for mem database
            #url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

            #Use for PostgreSQL database
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webInterfaceDev
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql:webInterfaceDev
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql:webInterfaceDev
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Below is the build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.2"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "web_interface"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    //plugins needed to make the user system
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.1.1'
    //end of the plugins needed
    //postgresql
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4.jre7'
    //end
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Below is the User.groovy code:

```
package com.domain.auth

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
    }

    static constraints = {
        password nullable: false, blank: false, password: true
        username nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table '`User`' //user is properity for postgresql insted i use now User as table name
        password column: '`password`'
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.groovy code:

```
package web_interface
import com.domain.auth.*

//class BootStrap {
//    def passwordEncoder
//
//    def init = { servletContext ->
//        def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority:"ROLE_ADMIN")
//        def user = User.findOrSaveWhere(username:"admin", password: "password").save(flush: true)
//        if(!user.authorities.contains(adminRole)){
//            UserRole.create(user,adminRole,true)
//        }
//    }
//    def destroy = {
//    }
//}


class BootStrap{
    def init = { servletContext ->

        if(User.count() == 0){

            def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush:true)

            def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'password').save(flush:true)

            UserRole.create admin, adminRole

            // as we call to create, flush the session explicitly ..
            UserRole.withSession {
                it.flush()
                it.clear()
            }

            // instead you can put >
            // new UserRole(admin, adminRole).save(flush:true)

            // Do more stuff with admin user

        }
    }
    def destroy = {

    }
}
```

UserRole.groovy code:

```
package com.domain.auth

import grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
import groovy.transform.ToString

import org.codehaus.groovy.util.HashCodeHelper
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@ToString(cache=true, includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    User user
    Role role

    @Override
    boolean equals(other) {
        if (other instanceof UserRole) {
            other.userId == user?.id && other.roleId == role?.id
        }
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = HashCodeHelper.initHash()
        if (user) {
            hashCode = HashCodeHelper.updateHash(hashCode, user.id)
        }
        if (role) {
            hashCode = HashCodeHelper.updateHash(hashCode, role.id)
        }
        hashCode
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        criteriaFor(userId, roleId).get()
    }

    static boolean exists(long userId, long roleId) {
        criteriaFor(userId, roleId).count()
    }

    private static DetachedCriteria criteriaFor(long userId, long roleId) {
        UserRole.where {
            user == User.load(userId) &&
            role == Role.load(roleId)
        }
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        def instance = new UserRole(user: user, role: role)
        instance.save(flush: flush)
        instance
    }

    static boolean remove(User u, Role r) {
        if (u != null && r != null) {
            UserRole.where { user == u && role == r }.deleteAll()
        }
    }

    static int removeAll(User u) {
        u == null ? 0 : UserRole.where { user == u }.deleteAll() as int
    }

    static int removeAll(Role r) {
        r == null ? 0 : UserRole.where { role == r }.deleteAll() as int
    }

    static constraints = {
        user nullable: false, unique: true
        role nullable: false, validator: { Role r, UserRole ur ->
            if (ur.user?.id) {
                if (UserRole.exists(ur.user.id, r.id)) {
                    return ['userRole.exists']
                }
            }
        user.save()
        }
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'role']
        version false
    }
}
```

Role.groovy code:

```
package com.domain.auth

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='authority')
@ToString(includes='authority', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    String authority

    static constraints = {
        authority nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code that calls User.save() .. also the params.

Comment: Looks like you have unsaved Role.

Comment: The code is generated by spring-security-core i don't now which part is for the User.save().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Bootstrap.groovy`, try simple thing as below

```
def init = { servletContext ->

  if(User.count() == 0){

        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush:true)

        def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'testpassed').save(flush:true)

        UserRole.create admin, adminRole

        // as we call to create, flush the session explicitly .. 
        UserRole.withSession {
            it.flush()
            it.clear()
        }

        // instead you can put > 
        // new UserRole(admin, adminRole).save(flush:true)

        // Do more stuff with admin user

    }
}
```

Just a small thing, put your db `url` in your application.yml

`url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDBName`

Comment: I have changed it to what you said but i get the same error. What do i wrong? I updated the code above to what i now have.

Comment: very unexpected outcomes. please upload your project in github and provide the link. the same code is running very fine at my production :P

Comment: I have chaged boostrap.groovy to ROLE_ADMIN2 and username to admin2. But stil it won't work. All the code can you find here: https://github.com/rm93/Grails_web_interface

Comment: cjhanged the DB too?

Comment: I think the problem is solved now. It turned out that I worked in a different folder than I started the grails project.

Comment: a bit surprised ... keep going, i found your app is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Long story in short**

Your `User.findOrSaveWhere(username:"admin", password:"password")` is the problem. If you try without `password:"password"` your code will run considering setting the password `user.password='password'` while initiating `new User`.

The saved password in the DB is hashed and it doesn't match with your given password. So, everytime you run the app, it doesn't find matching user and tries to save a new User with same `username` violating the `unique` constraints.

**Deatils** -

I tried with below codes -

```
    def xadminRole = Role.findOrSaveWhere(authority:"XYZROLE_XADMIN")
    def xuser = User.findOrSaveWhere(username:"xxzadmin", password:"password")
    if(!xuser.authorities.contains(xadminRole)){
        UserRole.create(xuser,xadminRole,true)
    }
```

First time its working fine and inserting the `User`

2nd time I ran the app i got user instance has below errors

```
Field error in object 'com.xxx.ovr.User' on field 'username': rejected value [xxzadmin]; codes [[username,class com.xxx.ovr.User,xxzadmin]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]
```

and finally

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.xxx.ovr.User
```

The user's password-

```
$2a$10$b1Ybjt9.XVgkDi.HRgGgpeyL7WsSFMFl0jpSWy60JfTfTDNRQH/Fu
$2a$10$8HTYeE8uJgmMzclc0lku5euUpNfqa3RUZeBBs7XaJ9Z5CpT/0Prtq
```

So you can not find a `user` with plain password - 'password' which is saved in DB after hashed (example given above). To match a user with username and password you can check the posts -

[spring security encode password with bcrypt algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303585/spring-security-encode-password-with-bcrypt-algorithm)

[Grails Spring-Security -how to compare passwords-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115991/grails-spring-security-how-to-compare-passwords)

**UPDATE**

With @BurtBeckwith's useful comment, I corrected the answer putting "hashed" in place of "encrypted"

For **Password Hash** algorithm, please check 1.2 and 3.3.2 section of
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/

**Related post**

[Using BCrypt password hashing with Spring Security Grails plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090418/using-bcrypt-password-hashing-with-spring-security-grails-plugin)

For difference between `Hash` and `Encryption` please check

[Difference between Hashing a Password and Encrypting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326699/difference-between-hashing-a-password-and-encrypting-it)

[Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to work out your suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: Very good answer, but one small issue. Passwords are hashed, not encrypted; encryption implies that it's possible to decrypt, but that's not possible here. To verify the password you hash a cleartext password and compare that to the stored hashed password (as described in the link you provided at the end of your answer).

Comment: @BurtBeckwith 
shall I correct the answer putting "Hashed" in place of "encrypted"

Comment: I have tried what you say but I still do not get it working.
I am new to grails (this is the first time).
Could you perhaps give an example on how I should apply it is this situation?

Comment: did you truncate the User table?

Comment: I don't now how do i do that?

Comment: In the first post of me I added the bootstrap.groovy code

Comment: create new DB then try